Is it possible to convert an image into a Tkinter Label?
I am quite inexperienced programing with Python and using the many available libraries for Python. I would like to be able to place an image /label  at a location on a Tkinter window. I've been looking for info on how to accomplish this,  so far no luck. I would very much appreciate any help or tips to help educate my Python adventure. Thanks in advance.
Thus far I've learned how to use Pillow how to open and resize a .png file.I hoped this could lead me to learning how to script this into aGUI window I have already created and works as I planed and expected. This is really making me feel Newby like. Again Thanks in advance.

It's difficult to offer relevant advice without a minimal reproducible example You can definitley add an image to a Label (you don't need PIL) if thats what you are trying to do. Are you looking for something like this

To insert images on tkinter widgets you must create a tkimage first, and then put it where you want to put it.
import tkinter


root = tkinter.Tk()

path_image = './src/frutas/umbu.png'
tkimage = tkinter.PhotoImage(master=root, file=path_image)

You can use the .zoom() or .subsample() to adjust the image size.
Exemple:
tkimage_smaller = tkimage.subsample(2)

Not recommended. Best get an image of the proper size (may preserve quality).

To insert an image on Label or Button do:
# If you want just the image
label = tkinter.Label(master=root, image=tkimage)

# If you want text and image
# compound ajust the image on widget region, left side in that case
button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text='Bem docinha kak', image=tkimage, compound=tkinter.LEFT)

Unfortunately tkinter do not support transparency, so Labels or Buttons will put a background on png images. 
Use Canvas if you want transparency.
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master=root)
canvas.place(x=0, y=0, width=500, height=500)

id_image = canvas.create_image((10, 10), image=tkimage)

# If you want to move around the image
canvas.move(id_image, 10, 10)

